# Half-duplex communication with VoIP

Tags: linux, voip

I'm trying to set up a half-duplex VoIP communication system. One client is walkie-talkie like radio, the other is a Linux system. My initial attempt was to use Twinkle, but after sniffing the network line through Wireshark, I found out that Twinkle is still sending out packets even if I mute it. The system only allows for half-duplex communication, so the Linux client is hogging the channel.

Is there a way I can either hodgepodge half-duplex on the Linux client or is there a VoIP client with G.711 u-law and PTT that only sends things out when keyed in? I did a search, but I couldn't find anything that had both.

EDIT: I wanted to add I did make a hack of two scripts that blocks all traffic going to the server and unblocks it, but I don't find this solution elegant at all.

Comment: SIP hold seems to be feature that you are looking for.

Comment: I tried that with Twinkle, and while the radio can transmit and I saw packets going through, the Twinkle effectively ignored them.

Comment: There are recvonly and sendonly attributes for SDP. They are not used too often so most likely you would have to dig into source code.